# SPARQL plugin for NEO4J 3.x

Tags: neo4j, sparql

Is there any working SPARQL plugin for NEO4J 3.x.x? This plugin code has license issue and it does not compile.
I have found a working code here https://github.com/niclashoyer/neo4j-sparql-extension. This code compiles but the plugin is not compatible with NEO4J 3.X.X.

Thanks

Comment: The code is open source, just adapt it to Neo4J v3.x ...